# how to loop through each row of every group (while doing "group by") in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to group by the table base on "customer_id" column and calculate "Day-day[0]" column. "Day-day[0]" is "Day" field in every group and "day[0]" is first row of the day in the group. At the same time, I have to calculate **total risk** which is in following:

This is the table after grouping by:

[image]

This is **total risk** formula:

[image]

In fact, I have to loop through each row of every group to calculate **total risk**.

My sample table is like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE risk_test
    (id          VARCHAR2 (32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id  varchar2 (40BYTE),
    risk number,
    day VARCHAR2(50 BYTE))

  insert into risk_test values(1,102,15,1);
  insert into risk_test values(2,102,16,1); 
  insert into risk_test values(3,104,11,1);  
  insert into risk_test values(4,102,17,2);
  insert into risk_test values(5,102,10,2);
  insert into risk_test values(6,102,13,3);
  insert into risk_test values(7,104,14,2);
  insert into risk_test values(8,104,13,2);
  insert into risk_test values(9,104,17,1);
  insert into risk_test values(10,104,16,2);
```

The sample answer is like this:

[image]

Would you please guide me how I can do this scenario in Oracle database?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in a text format (not an image) or insert statements to create the table as well as expected output from that sample data. Also, is there any primary key in the table?

Comment: Dear @EJ Egyed, thank you for your feedback. I add the sample table. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample data. What is the output from the select statement that you are hoping to achieve from this set of sample data?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient. I added sample data. Many thanks.

Comment: I've fixed my answer to match what you are expecting from the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sample data that was provided, I believe this query should calculate the risks properly:

#### Query

```sql
  SELECT o.*,
         ROUND (
               SUM (day_minus_day0 * risk) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id)
             / SUM (day_minus_day0) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id),
             5)    AS total_risk
    FROM (SELECT rt.*, (rt.day - MIN (rt.day) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id)) + 1 AS day_minus_day0
            FROM risk_test rt) o
ORDER BY customer_id, TO_NUMBER (day), TO_NUMBER (id);
```

#### Result

```sql
   ID    CUSTOMER_ID    RISK    DAY    DAY_MINUS_DAY0    TOTAL_RISK
_____ ______________ _______ ______ _________________ _____________
1     102                 15 1                      1      13.77778
2     102                 16 1                      1      13.77778
4     102                 17 2                      2      13.77778
5     102                 10 2                      2      13.77778
6     102                 13 3                      3      13.77778
3     104                 11 1                      1         14.25
9     104                 17 1                      1         14.25
7     104                 14 2                      2         14.25
8     104                 13 2                      2         14.25
10    104                 16 2                      2         14.25
```

Answer (score 2):

Your total risk calculation just looks like a weighted average to me.  That is, the average risk of the rows for each customer, weighted according to the day offset (day-day[0]), so that risks in later days count for more.

To compute that, you need a common table expression to 1st compute the day-weighted risk for each row.  Then you can just compute the weighted average by dividing.

The query below illustrates the approach, with comments.

```
-- This first WITH clause is just sample data.  In your database you would
-- get rid of this and replace all references to "input" with your actual
-- table name
with input ( customer_id, risk, day ) AS ( 
  SELECT 1053, 100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1053, 100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1053, 100, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1053, 100, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1053, 100, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1054, 200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1054, 200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1054, 200, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1054, 200, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1054, 200, 4 FROM DUAL
  ),
-- This CTE computes the day offset for each row and multiplies by the risk to 
-- compute a day-weighted risk.
-- I added +1 to the day_offset, otherwise risks on the 1st day would not contribute
-- to the total risk, which I think is not what you intended(?)
weighted_input AS (
  SELECT i.customer_id, 
         i.risk, 
         i.day, 
         i.day - min(i.day) over ( partition by i.customer_id ) + 1 day_offset,
         ( i.day - min(i.day) over ( partition by i.customer_id ) + 1 ) * i.risk day_weighted_risk
  FROM   input i )
-- This is the main SELECT clause that gets all the weighted risks and computes
-- the group total risk, which appears the same in every row in each group.
SELECT wi.*,
       sum(wi.day_weighted_risk) over ( partition by wi.customer_id ) / sum(wi.day_offset) over ( partition by wi.customer_id ) total_risk
FROM   weighted_input wi;
```

> ```
> +-------------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+------------+
> | CUSTOMER_ID | RISK | DAY | DAY_OFFSET | DAY_WEIGHTED_RISK | TOTAL_RISK |
> +-------------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+------------+
> |        1053 |  100 |   1 |          1 |               100 |        100 |
> |        1053 |  100 |   1 |          1 |               100 |        100 |
> |        1053 |  100 |   2 |          2 |               200 |        100 |
> |        1053 |  100 |   2 |          2 |               200 |        100 |
> |        1053 |  100 |   3 |          3 |               300 |        100 |
> |        1054 |  200 |   1 |          1 |               200 |        200 |
> |        1054 |  200 |   1 |          1 |               200 |        200 |
> |        1054 |  200 |   3 |          3 |               600 |        200 |
> |        1054 |  200 |   3 |          3 |               600 |        200 |
> |        1054 |  200 |   4 |          4 |               800 |        200 |
> +-------------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+------------+
> ```

For your database, having the actual table and not needing the `input` CTE, it would be:

```
WITH weighted_input AS (
-- This CTE computes the day offset for each row and multiplies by the risk to 
-- compute a day-weighted risk.
-- I added +1 to the day_offset, otherwise risks on the 1st day would not contribute
-- to the total risk, which I think is not what you intended(?)
  SELECT i.customer_id, 
         i.risk, 
         i.day, 
         i.day - min(i.day) over ( partition by i.customer_id ) + 1 day_offset,
         ( i.day - min(i.day) over ( partition by i.customer_id ) + 1 ) * i.risk day_weighted_risk
  FROM   my_table i )
-- This is the main SELECT clause that gets all the weighted risks and computes
-- the group total risk, which appears the same in every row in each group.
SELECT wi.*,
       sum(wi.day_weighted_risk) over ( partition by wi.customer_id ) / sum(wi.day_offset) over ( partition by wi.customer_id ) total_risk
FROM   weighted_input wi;
```

Comment: Dear @Matthew McPeek, thank you for your answer. I copied your code in toad but I received error. It did not accept weighted_input. It shows this error: **ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword.**  Would you please guide me?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Does TOAD use JDBC or Oracle Client?  If latter, what version of Oracle Client are you using?  Also, when you get rid of the the 'input' CTE you need to keep the 'WITH' keyword.  Post exactly what you ran.

Comment: I am using Oracle 19c. TOAD use Oracle Client which is **OraDB19Home1**. Many thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to show what you should be submitting to use your table instead of the `input` CTE (assuming your table is named 'my_table'.  Also, @EJ_Egyed posted an answer that is the same calculation using an inline view instead of a CTE.  You may have more luck with that.

Comment: Dear @Matthew McPeak, many thanks. It works now.